# Why does VS10 debug generate hundreds of script blocks files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging an asp.net mvc app and while in debug VS10 started generating all these script block files one after another,  why is this happening and how do I make it stop?

[image]

Comment: Are you debugging on IE8? Might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109103/why-do-script-blocks-grow-endlessly-in-vs2010-debugger-when-running-asp-net-page

Comment: Bit late now but this answers it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109103/why-do-script-blocks-grow-endlessly-in-vs2010-debugger-when-running-asp-net-page

Answer (score 0):

1. Run IE
2. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
3. In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
4. In the Browsing category, check the Disable script debugging check box.
5. Click OK.

Close Internet Explorer and VS, to make this option take effect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Darin, I verified and the checkbox is already checked like shown above.