# Visual studio debugger still shows old removed pages from iframes

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2008, iframe

I use modal dialogs. A modal dialog is build up with a mask div, and a container div. The container div contains an iFrame with the modal aspx page. When the modal dialog is initialized, the mask and container are added to the page body. When I close the modal dialog, the mask and container are removed from the body.

Everything works fine, and when I start debugging in Visual Studio, and open a new modal dialog, I see the new page in the debugger at 'script documents - Windows Internet Explorer - somePage.aspx'

But when I close and remove the dialog, the page just stays 'alive' in the VS debugger, until I refresh the complete page.

Is this bad? Does the page 'stay alive' somewhere even tho its removed from the body? Or is it just a Visual Studio debugger UI thingy?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109103/why-do-script-blocks-grow-endlessly-in-vs2010-debugger-when-running-asp-net-page), about endlessly growing script block files. I think thats the same issue, but that question is not really answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not enough** to remove the container div that contains the iframe.

I expected that this would be sufficient to remove and destroy the iframe:

```
$(this.mask).remove();
$(this.container).remove();
```

The container contains one other div (the modal dialog title) and an iframe.
That iframe **is not removed** by killing the container using the above code.
It looks like its not just a Visual Studio debugger issue, because the memory of the iexplore.exe process in windows task manager is also going up, and up, and up, every time I close and open a new dialog.

**Solution:**
When I explicitly remove the iframe, then the page does disapear from the debugger!

I can do that by saving the the iframe in a var on initializing the modal dialog, and then explicity remove the iframe when removing the modal dialog. This way:

on create / initialize modal dialog:

```
this.frame = this.container.childNodes[0].childNodes[1];
```

and on close modal dialog:

```
$(this.frame).remove();
```